# Redefinition of parameter $quotaMax error when using MWS to get product information

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I'm trying to get information from a product using Amazon MWS API and I'm get this annoying error:

**Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $quotaMax in....(path to file ResponseHeaderMetadata.php)**

My MWS credentials are ok because I tried the exact same credentials on the MWS scratchpad and the response was correct. My code are using the MWS samples for the Products API. I'm using the GetMatchingProductSample.php, the most important part are:

```
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$asin_list->setASIN(array("B01BH9EXX2"));

$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductRequest();
$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$request->setASINList($asin_list);

invokeGetMatchingProduct($service, $request);
```

When getting the dump of the request, all seems to be ok, again:

```
$parameters = $request->toQueryParameterArray();
var_dump($parameters);
```

**array(2) { ["MarketplaceId"]=> string(13) "ATVPDKIKX0DER" ["ASINList.ASIN.1"]=> string(10) "B01BH9EXX2" }**

The MWS API documentation is not very good.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Try following....

Open your MarketplaceWebServices->model->ResponseHeaderMetadata.php

Find and replace below code

```
public function __construct($requestId = null, $responseContext = null, $timestamp = null,$quotaMax = null, $quotaMax = null, $quotaResetsAt = null){
```

with

```
public function __construct($requestId = null, $responseContext = null, $timestamp = null,$quotaMax = null, $quotaRemaining = null, $quotaResetsAt = null) {
```

:)

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the above line change, the line:

```
$this->metadata[self::QUOTA_REMAINING] = $quotaMax;
```

should be changed to

```
$this->metadata[self::QUOTA_REMAINING] = $quotaRemaining;
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. Open file "MWSMerchantFulfillmentService/Model/ResponseHeaderMetadata.php"
2. **Replace** :

   public function __construct($requestId = null, $responseContext = null, $timestamp = null,$quotaMax = null, $quotaMax = null, $quotaResetsAt = null) {

   **With** :

   public function __construct($requestId = null, $responseContext = null, $timestamp =    null,$quotaMax = null, $quotaRemaining = null, $quotaResetsAt = null)
3. **Replace** :

   $this->metadata[self::QUOTA_REMAINING] = $quotaMax;

   **with** :

   $this->metadata[self::QUOTA_REMAINING] = $quotaRemaining;